# Install drupal project with drupal in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, ddev, drupal-9

My customer a has production environment with the following folder structure:

```
- www
|- maresmuseum
```

where I only have access to these two empty folders, being the "**maresmuseum**" the public_folder.

I've deployed my Drupal 9 site with composer, like the project-recommended way does, you know: placing the index.php along many other core related folders & files in "**maresmuseum**" folder, and /vendor, /tmp and many other private stuff in the "**www**" folder.

As a result, I can access my website through a url like this: `https://example.com/maresmuseum` (I'm quite sure my customer has a .htaccess rule somewhere to accomplish that, don't you?)

Given this production scenario, and having in mind I work with DDEV on local, I want to install this site on my local machine so I can access it with a url like this: `https://example.local/maresmuseum`.

Of course, all inner pages of this site must follow this url pattern, something like this:

`https://example.local/maresmuseum/about-us`

`https://example.local/maresmuseum/contact`, etc..

How should I configure DDEV to accomplish that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. Here's one way to do it using nginx configuration changes.

I used https://blog.rebootr.nl/drupal-8-in-a-subdirectory-with-nginx/

1. `ddev config --composer-root=maresmuseum --project-type=drupal9 --webserver-type=nginx-fpm --docroot=maresmuseum/web --create-docroot --web-working-dir=/var/www/html/maresmuseum` (This sets up to put composer.json in `maresmuseum`)
2. Install Drupal 9: `ddev composer create drupal/recommended-project --no-install`
3. `ddev composer require drush/drush`
4. Install project, or load db, or whatever, maybe `ddev exec vendor/bin/drush si -y demo_umami --account-pass=admin`
5. Edit the `.ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf` to remove the `#ddev-generated` and replace the location stanza, example in https://gist.github.com/rfay/5248e5f75bf3e27d84965bfdfc69c240#file-nginx-site-conf
6. Edit the `maresmuseum/sites/default/settings.php` to add the stanza suggested in the article to the bottom, example in https://gist.github.com/rfay/5248e5f75bf3e27d84965bfdfc69c240#file-settings-php
7. `ddev restart && ddev launch /maresmuseum`
8. `https://<project>.ddev.site/maresmuseum` will work fine (as it will without the directory).

I had some trouble with browser cache, so you'll want to pay attention to that.